# Как сократить слишком длинное выражение в условии if?

Tags: python

```
if sea_player[x1 + 1][y1] != 'S' and sea_player[x1][y1 + 1] != 'S' and sea_player[x1 + 1][y1 + 1] != 'S' and sea_player[x1 - 1][y1 ] != 'S' and sea_player[x1][y1 - 1] != 'S' and sea_player[x1 - 1][y1 - 1] != 'S' and sea_player[x1 + 1][y1 - 1] != 'S' and sea_player[x1 - 1][y1 + 1] != 'S' and sea_player[x1 - 1][y1 - 1]:
```

можно ли сократить этот участок кода?

p.s. пишу морской бой на питоне с использованием коммандной строки.
это условие проверяет,не граничит ли одноклеточный корабль при его установке с другими кораблями на поле(список из списков)

Comment: Можно использовать `numpy.array`, тогда проверка сводится на наличие `'S'` в выделенной области двумерного массива.

Comment: А что насчёт того, чтобы написать ф-ю замыкание, проверяющую нужное тебе условие, а в if её вызывать?

Comment: @mkkik, по-моему, это будет самым оптимальным решением... А как бы вы имплементировали "выделение окружаюшей матрицы" ?

Comment: @MaxU,  `array[nrow-1 : nrow+2, ncol-1 : ncol+2]`, где `nrow, ncol` - нужная клетка. Слайсы, разумеется, получать через лямбду.

Comment: @mkkik, не хотите оформить в виде решения? IMO, это будет явно быстрее и элегантнее остальных решений...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам список смещений для соседних ячеек лучше генерировать, чем руками писать:

```
adjacent_vector = [(x,y) for x in range(-1,2) for y in range(-1,2) if not (x == 0 and y == 0)]
```

Тогда точно не пропустите или не продублируете какое-то направление. Кстати у вас дважды проверяется одна и та же ячейка `sea_player[x1 - 1][y1 - 1] != 'S'`.

Список смещений можно один раз создать на все время работы программы.

Далее с помощью генератора и встроенной функции `any` можно проверить наличие 'S' в ячейках. Примерный код (не учитывает выход за границы вашего поля):

```
adjacent_vector = [(x,y) for x in range(-1,2) for y in range(-1,2) if not (x == 0 and y == 0)]
adjacent_cells = (sea_player[x1 + a[0]][y1 + a[1]] == 'S' for a in adjacent_vector)
if any(adjacent_cells):
    print 'found'
```

Функция `any` прекратит работу как только будет найдена первая ячейка с 'S', чтобы не тратить время на остальные ячейки (и генератор вместо списка здесь по той же причине).

Answer (score 2):

Можно представить поле так:

```
0 0 S
0 0 0
0 S 0
```

Так как у вас условие одно и большое, то этот квадрат можно представить не как двумерный, а как одномерный массив: `0 0 S 0 0 0 0 S 0`. Если карта - это двумерный массив `map` и координаты x, y - это центра квадрата для проверки, то получить одномерный можно операцией среза. В данном случае поле 5х5 и проверяем точку прямо по центру.

```
import itertools

my_map = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
          [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
          [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

y = 2
x = 2    
current = my_map[x][y]
my_map[x][y] = 'CURRENT'

arr = itertools.chain(*[row[max(x - 1, 0): x + 2] for row in map[max(y - 1, 0): y + 2]])

print(1 in arr)

my_map[x][y] = current
```

Лишний массив можно и не инициализировать. Замена текущей клетки нужна, чтобы исключить клетку из рассмотрения без сложных формул или условий.

Здесь было использовано несколько операторов:

1) Оператор среза ":" (slice). Пример использования:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

print(l[2:4])

>>> ['c', 'd']
```

2) Оператор распаковки коллекции "*" ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)):

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

print(*l)

a b c d e f
```

Суть оператора в том, что массив `l` превратился в 6 различных значений (был 1 список - стало 6 элементов без списка).

3) Функция `chain` из модуля `itertools` - склеивает массивы в один ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)):

```
l = itertools.chain(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'i', 'o'])

print(list(l))

>>> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'i', 'o']
```

4) Оператор in, который проверяет входит ли элемент в коллекцию или нет ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html)):

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

print('a' in l)
print('z' in l)

>>> True
>>> False
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение первое - вынести проверку в отдельную функцию, при этом имя функции будет самодокументировать код сообщая что она выполняет.

Второе - просто нормально отформатировать:

```
if    sea_player[x1 + 1][y1    ] != 'S' 
  and sea_player[x1    ][y1 + 1] != 'S' 
  and sea_player[x1 + 1][y1 + 1] != 'S' 
  and sea_player[x1 - 1][y1    ] != 'S' 
  and sea_player[x1    ][y1 - 1] != 'S' 
  and sea_player[x1 - 1][y1 - 1] != 'S' 
  and sea_player[x1 + 1][y1 - 1] != 'S' 
  and sea_player[x1 - 1][y1 + 1] != 'S' 
  and sea_player[x1 - 1][y1 - 1] != 'S'  :
```

Можно придумать другие более изошренные способы, на которые вы, видимо, и расчитывали задавая вопрос. Но они только ненужно усложнят код.

Comment: а нельзя двумя for-ами к примеру это сделать? Шансы опечатьтся ниже.

Comment: Совсем не факт, и даже напротив, просто потому что букв больше получится. На самом же деле акцент должен быть не на легкости написания, а на легкости понимания. Ваш исходный вариант понять в сто раз проще ибо он "статичен", в отличии от "динамических" циклов которые нужно интерпретировать в голове.

Comment: Если такой `if` встречается в коде более одного раза - выносить в функцию с кодом, отформатированном как в ответе. Если один раз - можно оставить как есть (желательно в отформатированном виде)

Answer (score 0):

Можно так перебрать (с проверкой на выход из диапазона):

```
for i in range(x1 - 1, x1 + 2):
    for j in range(y1 - 1, y1 + 2):
        if ((i < 0) or (j < 0)) or (i >= len(sea_player) or j >= len(sea_player)):
            if (i == x1) and (j == y1):
                continue
            if (sea_player[i][j] == 'S'):
                print('alarm')
```

Comment: А точно один `&` должен быть?

Comment: @gil9red должен быть один `and`